# how to select even records from a table in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

i'm using below query to retrieve even numbered records.but in reslut it is displaying no rows

```
select ename,job from emp where mod(rownum,2)=0;
```

why mod(rownum,2) is not working in where conditiom

can u please also give the query to select the odd number records

Is there anything wrong with that query?

suggetions please..

Answer (score 18):

It is not working because: for the first row `ROWNUM` is `1` and, in this case, `MOD(ROWNUM,2)` is `1` and since your `WHERE` statement is `MOD(ROWNUM,2)=0` then this reduces to `1=0` and the row is discarded. The subsequent row will then be tested against a `ROWNUM` of 1 (since the previous row is no longer in the output and will not have a row number), which will again fail the test and be discarded. Repeat, ad nauseum and all rows fail the `WHERE` test and are discarded.

If you try to get the odd rows this way using `WHERE MOD(ROWNUM,2)=1` then it will return the first row only and the second, and subsequent, rows will fail the test and will never be included in the query.

As Vijaykumar Hadalgi suggests, you need to select the ROWNUM in a sub-query (where it can number all the rows without a where clause to restrict it) and then in the outer query perform the test to restrict the rows:

```sql
SELECT ename, job
FROM   (
  SELECT ename,
         job,
         ROWNUM AS row_id             -- Generate ROWNUM second.
  FROM   (
    SELECT ename, job
    FROM   Emp
    ORDER BY ename                    -- ORDER BY first.
  )
)
WHERE  MOD( row_id, 2 ) = 0;          -- Filter third.
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c4e63/595)

Answer (score 5):

Try this

To find the **EVEN** number of row details you can use this code. 
*This one is comfortable in oracle SQL as well as MySQL.*

```
select * from (select ename,job, ROWNUM AS rn from emp) where mod(rn, 2) = 0;
```

To find the **ODD** number of row details you can use this code.

```
select * from (select ename,job, ROWNUM AS rn from emp) where mod(rn, 2) <> 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
-- for selecting rows 1,3,5,7....
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM 
(
  SELECT DENSE_RANK OVER(ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID)AS RANK, EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
  FROM EMPLOYEES
)
WHERE MOD(RANK,2)=1

-- for selecting rows 2,4,6,8....
SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID,FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME FROM 
(
  SELECT DENSE_RANK OVER(ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID)AS RANK, EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME
  FROM EMPLOYEES
)
WHERE MOD(RANK,2)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from emp where empid in (select decode(mod(rownum,2),0, empid,null) from emp);  --Alternate record Even numbered
```

Fetch even records from the table

Comment: above code is right first you execute the query @Sai

Answer (score 0):

Or You can try this:

Here The inner query will fetch all the even records primary key value and based on that we can get all those record details.

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO IN
( 
SELECT CASE MOD(ROWNUM,2)
        WHEN 0 THEN EMPNO
        END
FROM EMP
);
```

This will fetch all the odd records

```
SELECT * FROM EMP WHERE EMPNO IN
(
SELECT  CASE MOD(ROWNUM,2)
        WHEN 1 THEN EMPNO
        END
FROM EMP
);
```

Answer (score 0):

this will do :

```
Select * from (Select rownum as No_of_Row, E.* from emp E)
Where mod(No_of_Row,2)=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use the below query u will get the result:

```sql
SELECT empno,ename,slno  
FROM  ( SELECT empno,ename,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
(ORDER BY empno desc) AS slno FROM emp ) result WHERE mod(slno,2) = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below query,

```sql
select * from (select ename,job, ROWNUM as row_id from emp) where mod(row_id, 2) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ename, job from emp where mod(id, 2) =0 ;
```

You can Try the `id` column intead of `rownum` if table has an identity column

Answer (score 0):

We can use with clause

Example:

WITH Tab AS(select mod(rownum,2) AS R ,EMPLOYEES.* from employees)
SELECT * FROM Tab WHERE R = 0;

If you want odd rows then R = 1.

Example:

WITH Tab AS(select mod(rownum,2) AS R ,EMPLOYEES.* from employees)
SELECT * FROM Tab WHERE R = 1;

Answer (score -3):

Please try :

```
select * from emp where (rowid,0) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,2) from emp)
```

Output:-
2
4
6

```
Select * from emp where (rowid,1) in (select rowid, mod(rownum,2) from emp);
```

Output: 1,3,5..

Or this will work

this :

odd :

```
select * from
( 
SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS 'RowNumber', 
FROM table1
 ) d 
where (RowNumber % 2) = 1
```

even :

```
select * from
( 
SELECT col1, col2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY col1 DESC) AS 'RowNumber', 
FROM table1
) d 
where (RowNumber % 2) = 0
```

Comment: query working..but why mod(rownum,2) is not working in where conditiom

Comment: @TeamDataViz. the first two queries are not working!!

Answer (score -3):

row num represents row number in the results table not in the original table.
So, first assign it to row_id or any variable and use that variable.