# Oracle Function compilation error - Cannot find the reason of a PLS-00103

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

I am getting the errror:

```
Line/Col: 24/13
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following: (
```

When trying to compile the function:

```
create or replace function  xml_sum (innXML XMLType, outXML XMLType) RETURN number
  IS
 sum NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
        FOR j IN    
            (SELECT y.feature, rownum
                FROM    XMLTABLE
                    ('//FeatureVector/feature'
                      PASSING outXML
                      COLUMNS
                       feature  NUMBER  PATH '.') y)
                LOOP                    
                           FOR i IN
                      (SELECT x.feature, rownum rn
                        FROM    XMLTABLE
                            ('//FeatureVector/feature'
                              PASSING innXML
                              COLUMNS
                               feature  NUMBER  PATH '.') x WHERE rn = j.rownum) 
                    LOOP
                            sum := i.feature + j.feature;                    
                END LOOP;
        END LOOP;
  RETURN sum;
  END;
 /
```

By the error it seems that I am missing a ";" but I cannot find where it is being missed.

Could someone point it out? It would certainly help!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Change variable name `sum` to something other, let's say `v_sum_feature`  for start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution will not work as:

```
SELECT *
FROM   any_table
WHERE  ROWNUM = 2
```

[will never return any rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019043/1509264).

Apart from that, @XING noted a couple of other issues and you are overwriting the value in the `sum` variable in each iteration so you are only getting the last value.

You should be able to rewrite the procedure to remove the need for cursor loops:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/378cd0/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE FUNCTION xml_sum(
  innXML XMLType,
  outXML XMLType
) RETURN number
IS
  total NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  SELECT SUM( y.feature + x.feature )
  INTO   total
  FROM   XMLTABLE(
           '//FeatureVector/feature'
           PASSING outXML
           COLUMNS rn       FOR ORDINALITY,
                   feature  NUMBER  PATH '.'
         ) y
         INNER JOIN
         XMLTABLE(
           '//FeatureVector/feature'
           PASSING innXML
           COLUMNS rn       FOR ORDINALITY,
                   feature  NUMBER  PATH '.'
         ) x
         ON ( x.rn = y.rn );

  RETURN total;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT xml_sum(
         XMLTYPE( '<FeatureVector><feature>1</feature><feature>2</feature></FeatureVector>' ),
         XMLTYPE( '<FeatureVector><feature>1</feature><feature>2</feature></FeatureVector>' )
       ) AS total
FROM   DUAL
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/378cd0/2/0)**:

```
| TOTAL |
|-------|
|     6 |
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a Oracle reserved Key word `SUM`. Change it something else and your issue is resolved.

Also at this place:

```
WHERE rn = j.ROWNUM
```

you are referrring a column aliasing in where clause directly which is not allowed. Either you need a outer query or you can use it directly. You can see how i used it below:

So your code becomes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xml_sum (innXML XMLTYPE, outXML XMLTYPE)
   RETURN NUMBER
IS
   ToT_SUM   NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
   FOR j
      IN ( SELECT y.feature, ROWNUM
             FROM XMLTABLE ('//FeatureVector/feature'
                            PASSING outXML
                            COLUMNS feature NUMBER PATH '.') y)
   LOOP
      FOR i
         IN ( SELECT x.feature, ROWNUM rn
                FROM XMLTABLE ('//FeatureVector/feature'
                               PASSING innXML
                               COLUMNS feature NUMBER PATH '.') x
               WHERE ROWNUM= j.ROWNUM)
      LOOP
         ToT_SUM := i.feature + j.feature;
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;

   RETURN ToT_SUM;
END;
/
```