# Updating row, according to Rownum in Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-update, modulus, rownum

I have two tables in Oracle

**TableProducts**

```
Product_Code, and 20 others fields
    BGU
    LSO
    MPA
    MPA4
    MPA5
    TPA
    UGU
```

For this example, now I have 7 values, but maybe 9 values later.

```
CREATE TABLE TableContacts AS SELECT * 
FROM Contacts 
WHERE Rownum <= (4*(SELECT Count(Distinct Product_Code) FROM TableProducts));
```

Now I have 28 Rows in my **TableContacts**.

Now I need To UPDATE the rows in order to create combinations test.

**TableContacts**

`Product_Code`, `Email`, `PDF`, and 17 others fields.

`Email` and `PDF` has two possible values `'N'` or `'Y'`.

I need to fill the **TableContacts** with the combinations of `Product_Code`, `Email` and `PDF` fields, according to Rownum position.

`Rownum = 1` -> `Product_Code='BGU'`, `Email='N'`, `PDF='N'`

`Rownum = 2` -> `Product_Code='BGU'`, `Email='N'`, `PDF='Y'`

`Rownum = 3` -> `Product_Code='BGU'`, `Email='Y'`, `PDF='N'`

`Rownum = 4` -> `Product_Code='BGU'`, `Email='Y'`, `PDF='Y'`

`Rownum = 5` -> `Product_Code='LSO'`, `Email='N'`, `PDF='N'`

If I have 7 values for `Product_Code`, 2 by `Email` and 2 by `PDF`, then I will need to fill (7 * 2 *2) = **28 Rows**.

How to create and SQL for this situation updating **TableContacts**?

Answer (score 0):

Partially, requirement doesn't make sense. Rows in a table within the relational databases aren't sorted in any way, so - saying that you want to refer to a rownum is ... *strange*. That's why I modified the `contacts` table and added yet another column - `rn` - which shows that *rownum* of yours.

Also, this example shows only 3 products (didn't feel like typing all of them). Code that follows doesn't care about number of those products and will work the same regardless.

Products:

```
SQL> select * From products;

CODE
-----
BGU
LSO
MPA
```

Insert into Contacts:

```
SQL> insert into contacts (rn, code, email, pdf)
  2  with temp as
  3    (select p.code, x.lvl
  4       from products p cross join (Select level lvl from dual connect by level <= 4) x
  5    )
  6  select t.lvl,
  7    t.code,
  8    case when t.lvl in (1, 2) then 'N'
  9         when t.lvl in (3, 4) then 'Y'
 10    end email,
 11    --
 12    case when t.lvl in (1, 3) then 'N'
 13         when t.lvl in (2, 4) then 'Y'
 14    end pdf
 15  from temp t;

12 rows created.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * From contacts
  2  order by code, rn;

        RN CODE  E P
---------- ----- - -
         1 BGU   N N
         2 BGU   N Y
         3 BGU   Y N
         4 BGU   Y Y
         1 LSO   N N
         2 LSO   N Y
         3 LSO   Y N
         4 LSO   Y Y
         1 MPA   N N
         2 MPA   N Y
         3 MPA   Y N
         4 MPA   Y Y

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

---

**[EDIT: how to update table that contains rows?]**

If I understood you correctly, this is what you initially have in the `CONTACTS` table:

```
SQL> select code, rownum from contacts;

CODE      ROWNUM
----- ----------
BGU            1
LSO            2
MPA            3
BGU            4
LSO            5
MPA            6
BGU            7
LSO            8
MPA            9
BGU           10
LSO           11
MPA           12

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

As I previously said: rownum is irrelevant here, it can change, you can't tell which `rownum` belongs to which `code`.

Anyway, such an `update` (`merge`, actually) does the job:

```
SQL> merge into contacts a
  2    using (select c.code,
  3                  c.rowid,
  4                  row_number() over (partition by c.code order by null) rn
  5           from contacts c
  6          ) x
  7    on (a.rowid = x.rowid)
  8    when matched then update set
  9      a.email = case when x.rn in (1, 2) then 'N'
 10                     when x.rn in (3, 4) then 'Y'
 11                end,
 12      a.pdf =   case when x.rn in (1, 3) then 'N'
 13                     when x.rn in (2, 4) then 'Y'
 14                end;

12 rows merged.

SQL> select * From contacts order by code, email, pdf;

CODE  EMAIL PDF
----- ----- -----
BGU   N     N
BGU   N     Y
BGU   Y     N
BGU   Y     Y
LSO   N     N
LSO   N     Y
LSO   Y     N
LSO   Y     Y
MPA   N     N
MPA   N     Y
MPA   Y     N
MPA   Y     Y

12 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! Wow, I thought Is a big SQL, unfortunately I need to update, like initially I post. Then Is not possible?

Comment: What do you really have in the CONTACTS table? I understood that it is empty. Which columns does it have?

Comment: No problem about real situation; I don't understand the test. I saw you added CREATE TABLE for CONTACTS, but  - it looks wrong.

Comment: In my Contacts I have document, key, cut_date, directory, name_product, and others fields. The named fields (Product_Code, email, pdf) controls the behaviour of my application.

Comment: I was thinking some like https://stackoverflow.com/a/55276414/811293

Comment: I edited my answer and added some more code. Have a look, please.