# Select nth row Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pagination, rownum

I'm attempting to access the 3rd row from the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT
  OFFENSEDESC,
  COUNT(*) AS num
FROM
  CRIMEPROFILE

GROUP BY
  OFFENSEDESC
ORDER BY num DESC) o
WHERE rownum = 3
```

However, it returns no rows, I am uncertain as to why that is, any help is appreciated. NOTE: ORACLE SQL

Comment: Likely, the subquery returns less than 3 rows. Did you try to run the subquery alone to see what it returns?

Comment: No it returns 68 rows, oddly, rownum >= 3 works but I only want the 3rd row. Also no matter what index i chose (rownum = n) it returns no rows.

Comment: did you try with `rownumber()` ?

Comment: OFFSET 2 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY does the trick

Comment: See [how to select even records from a table in oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014495/how-to-select-even-records-from-a-table-in-oracle) for an explanation of why `ROWNUM = 3` doesn't work (or, in that case, why `MOD( ROWNUM, 2 ) = 0` doesn't work; but the explanation can equally work for `3` instead of even rows). The solution is that you need to `ORDER BY` first, generate the `ROWNUM` second and finally filter and do each of those steps in separate nested subqueries.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELCT
    OFFENSEDESC,
    num
from
(
    SELECT
      OFFENSEDESC,
      COUNT(*) AS num,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as rnk
    FROM
      CRIMEPROFILE
    GROUP BY
      OFFENSEDESC
) val
WHERE rnk = 3
```