# How to use ROWNUM in a recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following recursive CTE that starts from a row (a tree node) and goes up through ancestors to the root

```
with ancestor_seq (
    pre, parent
) as (
    select pre, parent
    from form_data_stage
    where pre = 16
    union all
    select d.pre, d.parent
    from ancestor_seq a 
    inner join form_data_stage d on d.pre = a.parent
)
select * from ancestor_seq;
```

It returns the expected result

```
pre parent
16  14
14  13
13  10
10  9
9   3
3   2
2   1
1   0
```

I want to get the 4th row only.  If I try the same query but with there ROWNUM condition at the end -

```
with ancestor_seq (
    pre, parent
) as (
    select pre, parent
    from form_data_stage
    where pre = 16
    union all
    select d.pre, d.parent
    from ancestor_seq a 
    inner join form_data_stage d on d.pre = a.parent
)
select * from ancestor_seq WHERE ROWNUM = 4;
```

I get an empty result.

I can add a level, e.g.

```
with ancestor_seq (
    pre, parent, lvl
) as (
    select pre, parent, 1 lvl
    from form_data_stage
    where pre = 16
    union all
    select d.pre, d.parent, a.lvl + 1
    from ancestor_seq a 
    inner join form_data_stage d on d.pre = a.parent and a.lvl <= 4
)
select pre, parent from ancestor_seq where lvl = 4;
```

this works -

```
pre parent
10  9
```

but it is checking the level value twice.  curious if there is a better way, and why rownum does not appear to work.

Comment: Rownum is a pseudocolumn that is assigned to the result set rows as they appear in the output. That's why the only valid equal comparison is `rownum = 1`. Why do you think that level value would be checked twice and why do you care about it (it is very cheap comparison relative to the coat of the recursive query itself).

Comment: If you want only the 4th row which means only one row will be returned by the query and if you have columns which can identify the  UNIQUENES then you can use the analytical function with partition and say ROW_NUMBER = 4. Also since you have two UNIONQ of 2 SQL you may have to do the ROW_NUMBER after you get the data from the 2 sql's. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Comment: From 12c and above there are handy `offset 3 fetch first 1 rows only` which do `row_number()` behind the scenes

Comment: "but it is checking the level value twice" - why is that a problem? Note that in your first attempt, the initial query may return 200 rows (assuming there are that many ancestors in the hierarchy), even though you are only interested in the first four. Certainly much more wasteful than "checking level value twice".

Comment: @mathguy yes you're right, its more that i'm looking for an elegant solution.  but from practical standpoint using level seems fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why `rownum` does not appear to work.

This is almost the same case as [my answer to this quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20019043/1509264).

It is not working because: for the first row `ROWNUM` is 1 and since your `WHERE` clause is `ROWNUM=4` then this reduces to `1=4` and the row is discarded. The subsequent row will then be tested against a `ROWNUM` of 1 (since the previous row is no longer in the output and will not have a row number), which will again fail the test and be discarded. Repeat, ad nauseum and all rows fail the `WHERE` filter and are discarded.

If you want to get `ROWNUM` to work then you need to generate it in an inner query and filter in an outer query:

```sql
with ancestor_seq (
    pre, parent
) as (
    select pre, parent
    from form_data_stage
    where pre = 16
    union all
    select d.pre, d.parent
    from ancestor_seq a 
    inner join form_data_stage d on d.pre = a.parent
)
SELECT *
FROM   (
  select a.*,
         ROWNUM AS rn
  from   ancestor_seq a
)
WHERE  rn = 4;
```